# Como se puede pasar parametros a esta funcion

Tags: php, javascript, upload

Seré breve, este código no es mio, me indicaron que lo utilizara para subir archivos al servidor, de entrada no tengo mucha experiencia en javascript estructurado de la manera que se ejemplifica.
Tengo un formulario HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title> Subir Archivos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="principal">
    <h1>Subir Archivos</h1>

        <form action="" id="form_subir">

            <div class="form-1-2">
                <label for="">Archivo a Subir:</label>
                <input type="file" name="archivo" required>
            </div>

            <div class="barra">
                <div class="barra_azul" id="barra_estado">
                <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="acciones">
                <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Enviar">
                <input type="button" class="cancel" id="cancelar" value="Cancelar">
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este html carga un ccs e  invoca a un js denominado main.js , donde se tiene esto:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() =>{
    let form = document.getElementById('form_subir');

    form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        subir_archivos(this);
    });
});


function subir_archivos(form) {
    let barra_estado = form.children[1].children[0],
        span = barra_estado.children[0],
        boton_cancelar = form.children[2].children[1];

    barra_estado.classList.remove('barra_verde', 'barra_roja');

    //Petición
    let peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();

    //Progreso
    peticion.upload.addEventListener("progress",(event) =>{
        let porcentaje = Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100);

        console.log(porcentaje);

        barra_estado.style.width = porcentaje+'%';
        span.innerHTML = porcentaje+'%';
    });

    //Finalizado
    peticion.addEventListener("load",() => {
        barra_estado.classList.add('barra_verde');
        span.innerHTML = "Proceso Completado";
    });

    //Enviar datos
    peticion.open('post','subir.php');
    peticion.send(new FormData(form));

    //Cancelar
    boton_cancelar.addEventListener("click", () => {
        peticion.abort();
        barra_estado.classList.remove('barra_verde');
        barra_estado.classList.add('barra_roja');
        span.innerHTML = "Proceso Cancelado";
    });

}
```

y este main a su vez llama o carga el archivo php que realiza la acción de subir el archivo "subir.php" este es el codigo contenido aqui.

```html
<?php
     $archivo_nombre = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
     $archivo_tamanio = $_FILES['archivo']['size'];
     $archivo_tipo = $_FILES['archivo']['type'];
     $archivo_nombre_temporal = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
     $array = explode(".", $archivo_nombre);
     $archivo_extension = end($array);

     $cambiar_nombre = null;
     $cambiar_nombre = sha1("ArchivoNuevo" . rand(0, 10000000));
     $archivo_nombre = $cambiar_nombre . "." . $archivo_extension;
     $archivo_nombre = preg_replace('/ /', '_', $archivo_nombre);
     $archivo_nombre = preg_replace('/%20/', '_', $archivo_nombre);
     $archivo_nombre = preg_replace('/:/', '_', $archivo_nombre);
move_uploaded_file($archivo_nombre_temporal, 'archivos/tmp/' . $archivo_nombre);
?>
```

hasta aquí todo trabaja bien, sin problema ,ahora el detalle es que requiero de pasar dos parámetros en especifico la extensión y el tamaño de archivo como parámetro desde una función...para validar el archivo que se esta subiendo.   Y pues la verdad no tengo mucha experiencia en javascript escrito de esta manera ya he leído algunos post de varios foros y visto video tutoriales y cada vez me hago mas bolas.

Si alguien pudiera explicarme un poco al respecto se agradece de antemano

Comment: Hola. Todos los parámetros a validar se encuentran en `$_FILES['archivo']` y esa validación debe hacerse del lado del servidor. Y, en este caso es independiente del JavaScript que usas. La validación será **php** consulta [$_FILES](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.files.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- Lo que yo te recomiendo es crear una funcion que se llame `validarArchivo()` esta funcion recibirá como parametro el `input file` quedando de la siguiente manera, en el codigo te comento cosas esenciales:

```
function validarArchivo(inputFile) {

  let file = inputFile.files[0];

  /*
    EN LA VARIABLE file VIENE INFORMACION DEL ARCHIVO EJEMPLO:
     - lastModifiedDate
     - name
     - size El tamaño esta dado en KB
     - type
  */

  /*
  REALIZAS LAS VALIDACIONES Y 
  SOLO CUANDO ESTAS SE CUMPLAN RESPONDES VERDADERO
  */

  if (file.type === "image/jpeg") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

2.- Necesitamos acceder a tu `inputFile` para poder obtener el archivo que seleccionó el usuario ejemplo:

```
let inputFile = document.getElementById("archivo");
```

3.- En tu evento submit mandas a llamar la funcion `validarArchivo()` y le pasas como parametro la variable que hay en `inputFile` quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    /*
      SOLO SI LA FUNCION validarArchivo me regresa true
      MANDAMOS EL ARCHIVO
    */ 

    if(validarArchivo(inputFile)){
      subir_archivos(this);
    }else{
      // REALIZAMOS OTRA COSA
    }
    
  });
```

4.- Si lo que deseas es enviar los parametros de validacion a tu servidor, te recomiendo crear una funcion llamada `parametrosValidacion` y esta funcion recibirá como parametros tus validaciones, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
function parametrosValidacion(ruta, tamanio, extension) {
  return {
    ruta: ruta,
    tamanio: tamanio,
    extension: extension,
  };
}
```

5.- NOTA que la funcion esta regresando un objeto, el cual sera enviado a tu servidor

6.- Entonces tu funcion de `subir_archivos` ya no recibira como parametro solo el formulario, si no tambien estos parametros de validacion quedando tu funcion de la siguiente manera:

```
function subir_archivos(form, parametrosValidacion) {}
```

7.- Entonces en donde realizas tu `submit` mandas el formulario y los parametros de la siguiente manera:

```
form.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    subir_archivos(
      this,
      parametrosValidacion("paramaetro1", "parametro2", "parametro3")
    );
  });
```

8.- Entonces la manera en la que realizas la petición cambiará te pongo en comentarios en codigo lo que cambiría:

```
function subir_archivos(form, parametrosValidacion) {
  //Petición
  let peticion = new XMLHttpRequest();

  /*
    AGREGAMOS UNA VARIABLE DATOS ESTO SERA UN FORMDATA
    Y LE PASAMOS EL FORM QUE RECIBIMOS COMO PARAMETRO
    ESTO TE PERMITIRA EN PHP MANEJAR $_FILES PARA
    TU ARCHIVO y $_POST PARA TUS PARAMETROS
 */
  let datos = new FormData(form);

  /*
    OJO CON JSON.stringify
    TENEMOS QUE MANDARLO DE ESTA MANERA
    PARA PODERLO MANIPULAR CORRECTAMENTE
    EN NUESTRO PHP
  */
  datos.append("parametros", JSON.stringify(parametrosValidacion));

  //Progreso
  peticion.upload.addEventListener("progress", (event) => {
    console.log(event.loaded);
  });

  //Finalizado
  peticion.addEventListener("load", () => {});

  //Enviar datos
  peticion.open("post", "app/subirArchivo.php");

  /*
    AHORA LO QUE MANDAREMOS ES datos
    Y datos LLEVA TANTO EL FORMULARIO Y 
    LOS PARAMETROS DE VALIDACION
  */
  peticion.send(datos);
}
```

9.- AHORA VAMOS CON **PHP** los archivos los recibes igual `$_FILES` pero los parametros de validacion los recibiras de esta manera:

```
$parametrosValidacion = json_decode($_POST['parametros'],true);
```

10.- Recuerda que mandamos un **JSON**, tenemos que manejarlo en **PHP** como tal

11.- Entonces ya puedes acceder a los valores que trae esa varible ejemplo:

```
echo $parametrosValidacion['ruta'];
```

12.- Espero haberte ayudado.

**NOTA: A TU ARCHIVO LE HICE MODIFICACIONES PARA PODER TESTEARLO EN MI PC SOLO AGREGA LO QUE TE COMENTO EN EL CODIGO**

Comment: Así es necesito validar tanto el tamaño como la extensión del archivo que se subirá.  Tengo varias dudas, primero como en el HTML poner en una variable tanto el tamaño y la extensión para pasarlas como un parámetro a la función.  He visto muchos codigos pero casi todos ponen dentro de script tanto la extension como el tamaño a validar.  Este detalle es importante por que se pretende que sea una funcion generica para ser utilizada en muchas secciones de un sistema.

Comment: Ya tengo las validaciones del lado del cliente, aunque no me las acepto mi jefe, ahora lo que requiero es realizar una funcion en js, digamos validarArchivo.js, dentro de esta colocar los parametros y pasarlos al main.js para que al momento de realizar el submit se envien al archivo subir.php junto con el archivo y asi poder validarlo.  Saludos

Comment: precisamente lo que tu me recomiendas que no haga, es lo que mi jefe quiere que se haga, el uso del send para enviar los parámetros junto con el archivo y que en el subir.php se haga la validación del archivo a cargar al servidor.

Comment: Interesante tu propuesta, pero tengo duda al respecto que me funcione como lo necesito.  El detalle radica en que me pidieron hacer una funcion que traiga dos o tres parametros, por ejemplo validarArchivo(ruta,tamaño,extension),  y estos valores definidos previamente ya que se pretende que la funcion se pueda reutilizar en muchos modulos diferentes, envie estos tres parametros al main para que de ahi, sean enviados por post utilizando send al archivo subir.php que es donde se validaria el archivo a subir

Comment: Ya tengo una validacion muy similar a lo que me comentas, solo que no esta en un archivo si no en el cuerpo del HTML,  le envio dos parametros tamaño y extension, al momento en que seleccionas el archivo, se llama y verificar que sea la extension y el tamaño, en caso negativo permanece bloqueado el boton de enviar, y en caso positivo habilita el boton para poder realizar el submit esto es del lado del cliente, ahora necesito que sea del lado del servidor pasando parametros al php

Comment: Asi es, solo ocupo declarar dos o tres parametros como ya sea como var, constantes ,incluso estoy  leyendo el tema de localStorage , y lo que no se es como enviar esos valores al main.js , que me permita recuperarlos ahi, y poder enviarlos con el send formdata al mismo tiempo que el archivo, se podra ?.  Saludos

Comment: No puedes añadir otra, ya que eso que propones le podria servir a alguien mas!!!!, para que no lo borres!!! :)

Comment: déjame modificar lo que ya llevaba, solo algunos detalles y el que si le voy a sufrir sera en el main por la estructura que tiene déjame probar y te comento que detalles surgen..

Comment: Esta linea que hace  //Enviar datos
@NikolaTesla que hace --->   peticion.open("post", "app/subirArchivo.php");  ???     no ubico o entiendo que hace esta linea app/subirArchivo.php ya que si bien tengo ese archivo en mi proyecto, no lo estoy usando el que tengo en uso en el proyecto es subir.php

Comment: En la consola en los Headers me aparece asi:  archivo: (binary)
parametros: {"ruta":"ruta","extension":"extension","tamanio":"tamanio"} dejame ver si en realidad toma los valores que le puse en las variables, a lo mejor no hay que declararlas como variables.

Comment: @Cesarin  recuerda que yo hice modificaciones a tu Script para poder testearlo en mi PC te recomiendo solo agregar lo comentado en el código y lo demás dejarlo como lo tienes petición.open lo eh modificado para poder hacer pruebas en mi PC por eso te comenté el código para que solo agregues lo comentado.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115413/discussion-between-cesarin-and-nikolatesla).